# Specifying multiple files when compiling from C++ to LLVM IR using clang

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang

I compile my C++ program to LLVM IR using the following command.

```
clang++ -O4 -emit-llvm program.cpp -c -o program.ll -S -pthread
```

However, now I want to do the same for multiple files. How can I do that? I want to produce one IR file after the compilation (not separate IR files for each file). In other words I want to have the linked code (code from all files linked together) in my IR file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [llvm-link](http://llvm.org/cmds/llvm-link.html) command, which links bitcode files together.